# Como expandir uma imagem com hover sem que os outros elementos se movam

Tags: html, css

gostaria de expandir uma imagem quando passar o mouse sem que as outras se movam.

```css
nav#foto ul li{
 
 display:inline-block;
 margin-left:30px;
 margin-top:55px;
 text-align: center;
 box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    background-color:rgb(248,248,248);

 
 }

 nav#foto li:hover{
 
  width:50px;
     height:40px;
  background:white;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 20px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  
 }
```

```html
<nav id="foto">
<ul>
<li id ="imagem1"><a href=""><img src="foto/foto1.jpeg"></a></li>
<li id ="imagem2"><a href=""><img src="foto/foto2.jpeg"></a></li>
<li id ="imagem3"><a href=""><img src="foto/foto3.jpeg"></a></li>
<li id ="imagem4"><a href=""><img src="foto/foto4.jpeg"></a></li>



</ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar a propriedade `transform` com `scale(largura, altura)` como alternativa:

Ela redimensiona o elemento de acordo com uma escala, e o mesmo não move os demais próximo a ele.

```css
nav#foto ul li{
    display:inline-block;
    margin-left:30px;
    margin-top:55px;
    text-align: center;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    background-color:rgb(248,248,248);
}

nav#foto li:hover {
    transform: scale(2, 2);
    background:white;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 20px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}
```

```html
<nav id="foto">
    <ul>
        <li id ="imagem1"><a href="">
            <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"></a>
        </li>

        <li id ="imagem2"><a href="">
            <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"></a>
        </li>

        <li id ="imagem3"><a href="">
            <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"></a>
        </li>

        <li id ="imagem4"><a href="">
            <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Não havia pensado nisso, realmente é um bom método.

Comment: O que pode dar problema é que por ser por escala imagens com tamanhos diferentes darão um efeito estranho, se expandindo mais ou menos que as outras. 

E seria necessário trabalhar com as margens ou overflow pra não deixar a imagens ultrapassar a tela, mas de ambas as formas isso é necessário.

Answer (score 2):

Uma das formas de fazer isso seria definindo um `margin` equivalente ao `width/height` quando o elemento está expandido.

Por exemplo:

```css
/* Padrão */
img {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  margin: 25px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
/* Expandido */
img:hover {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://img.ibxk.com.br/2014/03/18/18154237231274-t100x100.jpg">
<img src="http://img.ibxk.com.br/2014/03/18/18154237231274-t100x100.jpg">
<img src="http://img.ibxk.com.br/2014/03/18/18154237231274-t100x100.jpg">
```

Dessa forma o elemento padrão `margin` possui 1/4 do tamanho o `width` e `height` quando expandido. Enquanto o expandido terá o `margin` de `0`.